# Bind view model to data context of prism popup window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I am struggling with how to properly create a valid binding. I have a, say, `PanelA` which is a user control. It has a `InteractionRequestTrigger` defined as follows

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding EditRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <view:Editor DataContext="{Binding Path=EditorVM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

So when view model of `PanelA` triggers interaction a new popup window with view `Editor` should open.

Previously I used DI to inject the view model right into the `Editor` but I cannot do that as it will change depending on user actions time. So in view model of `PanelA`, I added a property `EditorVM` that contains the view model for this popup and I am trying data context of the `Editor` to it. Obviously I have the path wrong.

This is the error I get:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference
'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''.
BindingExpression:Path=EditorVM; DataItem=null; target element is 'Editor' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

I also tried

```
<view:Editor DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditorVM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

with similar results

### Edit

I solved the issue by just sending that dependency through notification and I use   DI to set data context, but I am still curious how bind data context to property.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

```xml
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding EditRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <view:Editor>
                   <view:Editor.DataContext>
                      <local:EditorVM/>
                   </view:Editor.DataContext>
                </view:Editor>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: But is DataContext of vm actually bound to some vm that can be replaced? Because this is what I was asking  about. Injecting vm once is not a problem.